# Dynamics CRM Online - push data when a contact is created

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

We are trying to push data to Azure Service Bus Queue when a contact is created in "Dynamics CRM Online". We have implemented it using a plugin by registering it with Plugin Registration Tool. But somehow its throwing an error while saving the contact. 
Here is the code which we have implemented in plugin:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        try
        {                
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            if (entity.LogicalName.Equals("account"))
            {
                QueueDescription qd = new QueueDescription("testQ");

                qd.MaxSizeInMegabytes = 5120;
                qd.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

                string connectionString =
                    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Endpoint=sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=secretcode=");

                var namespaceManager =
                    NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
                if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists("testQ"))
                {
                    namespaceManager.CreateQueue("testQ");
                }

                QueueClient Client =
                    QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "testQ");

                BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(entity);

                message.Properties["FirstName"] = "ABC";
                message.Properties["LastName"] = "Z";

                Client.Send(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
}
```

Comment: please add also the error message

Comment: **Business Process Error**
Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples.Account: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Are you using a tool like ILMerge to to merge all the dlls you have referenced?

Comment: Yep. we have tried it but didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing the DLL?
You must add a local reference (not GAC). 
Eg: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Azure platform AppFabric SDK\V1.0\Assemblies\NET4.0\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll

Also, set "Copy Local" to true so that the assembly is packaged with your plugin.

Comment: i have added service bus dll through NuGet.

i have tried adding appfabric servicebus dll. it doesn't contain CreateFromConnectionString method.

Comment: Download the SDK from here and add the references manually. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/?fb=en-us The NuGet package could be missing the assembly.

Comment: the above link sdk doesn't contain servicebus.dll. we already tried it. Is der any other solution to push data out from CRM Online?

Comment: Sorry, you should be able to find the dll in the App Fabric SDK http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19925

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Dynamics CRM 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40321) examples at `\SDK\SampleCode\CS\Azure`
If you haven't been updated to going to assume you've been upgraded to the Fall ’13 release you should look at the same location in the [Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004). It won't work exactly as you have it - but you can meet all you requirements using the supported method.

You need to use the Azure Plugin functionality that is in Dynamics CRM. I would add the details but they are too long and best read with the pictures: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/02/18/windows-azure-appfabric-integration-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-step-by-step.aspx